# Extra empty lines appear when copying to the terminal org.kde.konsole

Tags: command-line, terminal, archlinux, kde-plasma, manjaro

My problem is as follows. When copying multi-line text (consisting of commands, for example) from somewhere (text editors, etc.) to the terminal via Ctrl + Shift + V or through the menu with the right mouse button, extra empty lines appear between each line.

For me, this is a problem when copying, for example, the body of a function to the Python interpreter.

My system is Linux Manjaro-KDE (5.4.43-1-MANJARO kernel), but the problem repeats in Arch-linux-KDE too (I checked this).

I managed to figure out the following on my own:

When copying multi-line text, in the Clipboard (which I view by clicking on the corresponding tray icon) a blue “Enter” icon is in front of each new line of the text.

If I edit the block with text directly in the Clipboard buffer, for example, press "edit", do nothing and just save, then the blue "Enter" disappears and the text is copied to the terminal without any extra intermediate lines.

As for other editors and exactly for the gnome-terminal, the text is copied everywhere correctly without blank lines, regardless of the "existence" of the blue "Enter" in the Clipboard. In addition, if I copy lines from the terminal itself and paste into it, then empty lines do not appear.

I think that additional CR/LF characters are added, which are perceived by a single line break everywhere except for the terminal "org.kde.konsole".
Please help: how can I change the behavior of the buffer when copying or the behavior of the terminal?

This question is similar to https://forum.manjaro.org/t/copy-paste-multiple-lines-on-yakuake-konsole-adds-newlines/94589 but it didn't help me.

Comment: I'm happy to report that after so many days the problem went away by itself. Apparently, together with some of the latest system updates or kde.konsole itself.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it was fixed in Konsole 20.04.3 by the following commit: https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/-/commit/6b6a1e552492a25217cded1d83c25a652e5b249a

Comment: this problem appeared for me in kubuntu 21.10 and Konsole 21.8.1